# How can I define an array in this case?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

I have a object:

**myObj.js**

```
MyObj={

  myArray: new Array(),//An ARRAY DEFINED HERE, BUT seems should be somewhere else

  test_1: function(){
     //HERE!!! Modify "myArray"
  },

  others: function(){

  }

}
```

**myfunc.js**

```
var myFunc= function(){

};

myFunc.prototype={

  start: function(){
    for(var i=0; i<DynamicNumber; i++){
         MyObj.test_1
    }
  }
}
```

I run the code by:

```
var my = new MyFunc();
my.start();
```

As you saw, when `my.start()` run, it calls the `test_1()` function to modify the `myArray` multiple times in **MyObj**, I would like to define the `myArray` in some where so that every time when `test_1()` is run, it knows the **current content** of `myArray`. That's I would like `MyObj.test_1()` function be aware of the **current content** of '`myArray`' after every modification. Keep tracking '`myArray`'.

Where and how can I define this 'myArray' ?

Comment: you have myObj and MyObj and myFunc and MyFunc - that will not work

Comment: have you had a look at my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a constructor:

```
MyObj = function() {
    var myArray = new Array();

    var test_1 = function() {

        // In this scope, you will have access to myArray

    };

    var others = function(){

    };

    //Public variables
    this.test_1 = test_1;
    this.others = others;
}
```

And use it:

```
myFunc.prototype={

  start: function(){

    var myObj = new MyObj();
    for(var i=0; i<DynamicNumber; i++){
         myObj.test_1();
    }
  }
}
```